# How to plot a scatter plot to understand the general trend in data, when we have multiple features

Tags: python, machine-learning, feature-selection, sklearn-pandas, feature-engineering

Here,
Features are X_train
Target is y_train

W​hen there is a dataset with 'n' number of features how will we select that one feature to make a scatter plot with the target variable to understand the general trend of the training data, to select a suitable model.

D​o we consider that feature which is correlating with the target the most?

H​ow to plot a scatter plot when we have multiple features

Considering this is the data set

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression

X, y = make_regression(n_samples=100, n_features=10, n_informative=3,n_targets=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `seaborn.pairplot()` it shows relationship between each features that are numerical.